# Custom URI schema for a Linux application

Tags: linux, uri

I would like to use a custom URI schema to open my application from a wepage in the browser. It is quite easy on OS X and iOS, it seems to work on Android and it is possible on Windows but I need it for Linux.

What it should do is if there is a link like this in a webpage:

```
<a href="bungloo://?code=1234">Open in Bungloo</a>
```

then it should open my own app (called Bungloo) and give it this URL so I can use it to do stuff.

I need that for OAuth authentification callback. I can not use a custom webview to do that because very often those use old versions of webkit which doesn't support CORS which the provider uses in the Authentication process. I neither can turn off cross origin security for the webview because this functionality is not exposed to PyWebkit which I use.

I also understand that I need to do that in some way for every desktop environment (at least KDE and Gnome) but sadly I am not able to find any documentation on about how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/) for GNOME and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150426082221/http://www.lastfm.de/forum/21714/_/42837/1) for KDE?

Have you tried [this](http://archive.is/8C3zb)?

Comment: The last one looks promising. When I try that Firefox opens the "Launch Application" window but sadly with a empty list of application so you as a user'd need to know where on your hard drive to find the application, see: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BVk4f2DCUAEN0I8.png